# How to move the WPF tabHeader leftward?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I plan to add in my logo into my wpf project. I use tabControl in my project and since i want to add in my logo, i wish to move the first Tab Header leftward so that my logo can fit in(as what shown in the second image ). Anyone know how to move the tab header position?

My project now:

[image]

After moving my tab header, the my project will be something like this:

[image]

p/s: i photoshop the second image, i'm not making it from the coding.

Comment: wrap the tab with any panel Grid For example

Comment: i tried, if  i wrap it to the grid...the whole tab control will be wrapped together with the tab header.

Comment: add an example of the code you tried to use.

Comment: Can you show me a simple example please?

Answer (score 0):

you might change TabControl's template

1.Use this style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
2. Add three columns to the grid
3. Set HeaderPanel's Grid.Column to be "1"

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    //*
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>     //*
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    //*
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     //*
      <TabPanel 
        Name="HeaderPanel"
        Grid.Row="0"

        Grid.Column="1"   //*

        Panel.ZIndex="1" 
        Margin="0,0,4,-1" 
        IsItemsHost="True"
        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
        Background="Transparent" />
      <Border 
        Name="Border" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        CornerRadius="2" 
        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" >
        <ContentPresenter 
          Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
          Margin="4"
          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
      </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramin's solution works pretty well.  **A couple of additional notes about using that approach**:

First, you'll need to add a `ColumnSpan` to the Border so that the main Tab content extends to the full width of the control:

```
<Border Name="Border" 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        ...
```

Second, these ColumnDefinitions:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> 
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

will *center* the tab headers.  If you just want the first one shifted rightward enough for a logo or something, then specify a different width for the first column definition.

I worked up a quick example using these column definitions:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- the width to shift the first tab rightward (i.e., to make room for a logo)-->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="87"/>  
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>    
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>   <!-- any extra space goes on the right -->
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

...to produce this:

[image]